# Trying to get a variable to equal an object from a set of objects...i think?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, coffeescript

OK so the way i worded this question before must have been too convoluted so here is a simplified version:

I have a variable which equals:

```
{
  txid: 'f0315ffc38709d70ad5647e22048358dd3745f3ce3874223c80a7c92fab0c8ba',
  version: 1,
  locktime: 0,
  vin: 
   [ { coinbase: '0420e7494d017f062f503253482f',
       sequence: 4294967295 } ],
  vout: [ { value: 50, n: 0, scriptPubKey: [Object] } ],
  blockhash: '00000000b873e79784647a6c82962c70d228557d24a747ea4d1b8bbe878e1206',
  confirmations: 39288,
  time: 1296688928,
  blocktime: 1296688928 }
```

I want to make another variable equal just:

```
vout: [ { value: 50, n: 0, scriptPubKey: [Object] } ],
```

How do i do this?
When i try:

```
varible2 = variable1.vout
```

I get back an error saying ".vout" is undefined

Comment: First of all, those aren't arrays.

Comment: alright so i am a noob....regardless of that could you help me in understanding why the .vout is coming back undefined?

Comment: wow just relized the vout part of the code is cut off

Comment: I don't know why it's coming back undefined, it looks like it should be fine to me. I just wanted to point out to you that those are objects, not arrays.

Comment: alright thank you...sometimes i am worried people oin here will attack me for dumb questions so i was on defense mode =P

Comment: What do you mean by "rawTxVouts = rawTx.vout comes back as undefined"? It would help if you posted a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: it is telling me that rawTx.vout is undefined despite the fact that rawTx has a vout object...not sure how else to explain it =/

Comment: An example, like Aaron asked for, would explain it.

Comment: not sure how to use jsfiddle so i reworded my question to make more sense...?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/McwzB/ Btw your object in the question is doubled, and won't work like this. See the fiddle

Comment: @AndrewFont: Ah, you get an error. If you get that error, `variable1` does not really equal the object you posted. Please show us how, when and where you (try to) assign that value to the `variable1`, and when you try to access its `vout` property to assign to `variable2`.

Comment: for some reason hitting run doesn't work...also yea somehow i added the bottom half twice lol, but the problem remains

Comment: @Andrew Well, I see the object representation in my console

Comment: @Dan the exmaple you sent me should work and its what i have in my orignal code but when i run the JS i still get back       rawTxVouts = rawTx.vout[0];
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vout' of undefined

Comment: There must be some circumstances we are not aware of. Maybe you should give more context

Comment: you have tagged this as a CoffeeScript question, are you using CoffeeScript? if so share your code. Also, are you getting the contents of that variable asynchronously?

Comment: wow you made me realize the issue...it was running in async and was trying to get the value of varibale2 before it had variable1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var avariable = {/* your object [literal] here */};

var anothervariable = avariable.vout; // or avariable["vout"]

// or did you want the following?

var anothervariable = {
    vout: avariable.vout
};
```

Comment: I have just like you placed above but i still get back variable2 = variable1.vout; ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'vout' of undefined

Comment: and like i said if i log variable1 i get back the exact thing i placed in my quesiton above., but i can't get variable2 = variable1.vout

Comment: If `variable1` is `undefined`, it does not equal to the given object as proposed. Use a `console.log(variable1)` right before you (try to) access the property, and it will yield `undefined`.

Comment: no thats the porblem console.log variable1 gives me the set of data from my example of above... it is telling me that .vout is undefined when i make vairable2 = variable1.vout

Comment: Not if you do it successively: `console.log(variable1), console.log(variable1.vout);`. Please show us your log statements and where you try to access the property. I'm sure there is something happening in between.

Comment: thank you that worked...it was running in async and it was trying to get variable2 before it had variable1